# how to create a deinterlacer in xinimin.c (xine)

Tags: c

I've taken xinimin.c and added seek and osd functionality.  The last big piece that I need to implement is deinterlacing, however, I'm finding very little documentation.  I've been through the hacker's guide and of course I haved googled and googled.  I found the deprecated method:

```
xine_set_param(stream, XINE_PARAM_VO_DEINTERLACE, 1);
```

which did not work.  I saw that the current method involves post plugins, but my /usr/include/xine/post.h doesn't have the word deinterlace in it.

Can anyone provide an example of how to implement deinterlacing.  It would be nice to have the flexibility down the road to change the deinterlacer, but something equivalent to the -D option on the command line is what I'm looking for to start with.

Is there a good resource for example source files?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? `src/post/deinterlace` directory:

(4 links to pretty much the same:)

- [debian.org/hg/xine-lib](http://anonscm.debian.org/hg/xine-lib/xine-lib/file/2a87c8b39a0a/src/post/deinterlace)
- [github || huceke/xine-lib-vaapi/tree/master/src/post/deinterlace](https://github.com/huceke/xine-lib-vaapi/tree/master/src/post/deinterlace)
- [fossies dox ** xine-lib 1.2.1, deinterlace.h File Reference](http://fossies.org/dox/xine-lib-1.2.1/xine__plugin_8c_source.html)
- [xine_plugin.c File Reference](http://fossies.org/dox/xine-lib-1.2.1/xine__plugin_8c.html)

From [hackersguide - Walking the source tree](http://www.xine-project.org/hackersguide#id278352):

**post**
    Video and audio post effect plugins live here. Post plugins
           modify streams of video frames or audio buffers as they leave
           the decoder to provide conversion or effects.

```
  deinterlace (imported)
        The tvtime deinterlacer as a xine video filter post.
```

[hackersguide, Plugin system](http://www.xine-project.org/hackersguide#id326512)

### Edit:

---

I have only installed libxine, not anything else.

It is however a good idea to download [the source](http://www.xine-project.org/repository) as the project in large part is documented in the code. If you use i.e. [Vim](http://www.vim.org/) it is nice to use it with [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) and/or ctags. (As show in this [tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/04/ctags-taglist-vi-vim-editor-as-sourece-code-browser/).). Then you can jump to functions, definitions, callers, ... (across files etc), simply by a couple of key strokes. (They map where every function is defined, called, etc.)

When compiling, if on linux at least, I have to add the lib's at end (after source file):

> gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c89 -o muxine muxine.c -lX11 -lxine

---

Perhaps this'll get you further on the way: Using sample code, [muxine.c](http://www.xine-project.org/samplecode),:

And reading source documentation, (mainly here): [xine.h](https://github.com/huceke/xine-lib-vaapi/blob/master/include/xine.h)

I added in main:

---

```
const char* const *tmp;
xine_post_t *post_x;
xine_post_api_t *post_api;
xine_post_in_t *input_api;
xine_post_api_descr_t *param;

const char *post_plug_t = "tvtime";
/*const char *post_plug_d = "deinterlace";     perhaps this?? */
```

After the existing sample code:

```
ao_port     = xine_open_audio_driver(xine , ao_driver, NULL);
stream      = xine_stream_new(xine, ao_port, vo_port);
```

---

I added

```
/* get a list of all available post plugins */
if((tmp = xine_list_post_plugins(xine)) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to get post plugins\n");
    xine_exit(xine);
    return 1;
}
printf("Post plugins:\n");
while (*tmp != NULL)
    printf("  %s\n", *tmp++);

/* initialize a post plugin */
if ((post_x = xine_post_init(xine, post_plug_t, 1,
                &ao_port, &vo_port)) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, " *ERR: Unable to 'post init' %s;\n",
            post_plug_t);
    xine_exit(xine);
    return 1;
}

/* get a list of all outputs of a post plugin */
tmp = xine_post_list_outputs(post_x);
printf("Post List Outputs:\n");
while (*tmp != NULL)
    printf("  %s\n", *tmp++);
```

---

! I get at least tvtime. Believe that is the deinterlacing plugin. (Sounds like it when reading the src/post/... comments.

---

One have the struct `xine_post_api_t` whic in turn has `set_parameters()`, that can be used to control the plugin (from the looks of it).

Comment: Thank you @user120115. I did see that snippet in the hackers guide, but unfortunately that does very little to demonstrate how it is implemented.  I have xine-lib ver 1.2.1 installed, but I'm afraid I don't have the right use flag set (gentoo) because I don't have any of those header or source files in my system.  Unfortunately none of the unset flags jumps out at me as the one that needs to be set.  The links you provided should get me to where I want to be, just need to get my system configured properly first.  Thanks again.

Comment: As you might have guessed by now, I am new to C/C++ but I am learning.  I am clueless as to how to proceed.  Since I don't have these headers and source files on my system, do I copy them into my working dir?  I don't need all the capabilities of a complete post processor.  So I don't need everything in these files.  Any hints as to which parts are required?  I'm not going to make money on this project, and it is not a school assignment.  I'm just trying to learn.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: @nomadicME: Only to clarify: You do not _include_ any of those source files (from repository) but use them as a reference doc. The includes are done with installed library and using either -lxine or `$(pkg-config --cflags --libs libxine)`. If you are not to familiar with GCC this is a great read: http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/index.html

Comment: Thank you @user120115 for the guidance.  You've given me quite a bit to go on.  I'll work on it for a while, read the gccintro, and post back how it goes.

Comment: Well, I looked at it off and on over the last couple of days and I'm just not getting it.  I agree with you that I should be able to use set_parameters() to control the tvtime plugin, but what are the names of the parameters?  I want to list them, but I can't figure out how.  I have /usr/lib/xine/plugins/2.1/post/xineplug_post_tvtime.so in my system (installed by xine-lib), but can't find any documentation.  I googled and found this [page](http://www.linuxtv.org/pipermail/vdr/2008-July/017296.html)

Comment: get_parameters() in xine.h requires xine_post_t as the type for the first argument, so I came up with this:  int method  = get_parameters( post_x, Linear ); but it does not work.  Linear has not been defined, it does not recognize it as a parameter. I read xine.h, which is very well documented and tvtime.h (not a whole lot there). I'm not really sure where to go from here.  I'll keep looking and searching.